# How to replace data in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I am currently a novice in R (I have the basics, that's all), and I have a small issue in a data frame :

[image: Data frame in question]

What I want to do here is :

- For all elements in the Wage column, replace the 'K' with '000'
- For all elements in the Value column : if the cell contains a '.', then replace the 'M' with '00000', if not, then replace it with '000000'

I guess this could by achieved with a for loop, but after trying I can say that I am not used to it.

Thanks for your answers,

Rémi

Comment: Hi, please consider editing your question to add the output of `dput(head(dataframe,20))` rather than an image. Also sample code of what you've tried is appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution similar to this is probably more comprehensive:

```
parseBigNumbers <- function(vec) {

  vec <- gsub("K", "e+3", vec)
  vec <- gsub("M", "e+6", vec)
  as.numeric(substr(vec, 2, nchar(vec)))

}

df$Wage <- parseBigNumbers(df$Wage)
df$Value <- parseBigNumbers(df$Value)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked too ! I might go for this solution because I might have other columns where I need to use this method.  Thanks !